# Show detail Button in table not working(instead pages gets reload) and Not getting all the data properly of the table from mongodb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, onclick, preventdefault

As I click on the Show detail button I should get an alert/more info of the user but instead of that the page gets reload. Basically on 'show details' button the 'OnClick' function is not getting executed.

Why am I getting no enteries found after clicking on 'show details'
[image]

Fetching data from Database and setting it in 'clientTable' variable:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
    window.onload=()=>{
        const datatablesSimple = document.getElementById('datatablesSimple');
        if (datatablesSimple) {
            new DataTable(datatablesSimple);
        }
         const fetchClients = async ()=>{
         const res = await axios.get("/users")
         setClientTable((clientTable)=>{return clientTable=res.data;})
         console.log(clientTable)
        }
        fetchClients()
    }
    
},[]);
```

Nodejs code for fetching all the Clients

```
router.get("/", async(req, res) => {
try{
    const allclients = await User.find();
    res.status(200).json(allclients);
}catch(err){
    res.status(500).json(err);
}  
});
```

HTML code of rendering the table in frontend:

```
    <tbody>
         {clientTable.map((User, index)=>(<>
          <tr key={index}>
          <td>
             <Link to="/details" state={User}    
                   style={{textDecoration:'none', 
                   color:'black'}} > {User.username} 
             </Link>
          </td>
            <td>{User.email}</td>
            <td>{User.dob}</td>
            <td>{User.city}</td>
            <td>{User.services}</td>
             <td><button onClick={handleRowClick}> show details</button></td>                                                                                  
          </tr> 
      </>
     ))}
    </tbody>
```

handleRowClick method implementation:

```
const handleRowClick =  (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Hello")
    //setShowPopup(true);
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason that use are using window.onload=()=>{ inside the useEffect? Normally that is not needed. Other than that by the looks of it the code you posted it looks fine. Can you post some more code?

Comment: @Poku windows.onload() is used to run that code every time page is reloaded or Dom content is loaded.  But even after removing window.onload() and direct code inside useEffect() , it is giving the same issue

Comment: The useEffect does that for you so you don't need the window.onload(). Can you post more code because the code you already posted looks good to me. Maybe the error is somewhere else? The code looks pretty basic for now maybe you can recreate the issue in a https://codesandbox.io/ example?